# URL in link field adds duplicate parameters in query string when using an internal relative path

Tags: theming

Newbie Drupal 8 user using a link field to add url's like:

/samples/products?f%5B0%5D=market%3A1

when saved makes the actual link /samples/products?f%5B0%5D=market%3A1&f%5B1%5D=market%3A1&f%5B2%5D=market%3A1

It's really /samples/products?f[0]=market:1 encoded so maybe the link field doesn't like this? Adding links like this in other places like in wysiwyg editors work fine it seems that the link field is adding two more times.

Any ideas on where that might be happening? Could there be a bug in link module or is there an issue with using internal url's this way? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a bug in Core at the moment. Follow the issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2885351

Seems like a workaround currently is to use full paths instead of relative ones or use the patch in the issue above to patch core.

There seems to be a module someone made too since patching core isn't ideal:
https://www.drupal.org/project/link_formatter_query_fix